What is the best way to suppress intellisense when displaying inline completions?
Cross-posting from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/1161
I noticed that a suppressSuggestion attribute was added to InlineCompletionItem in proposed state. It was then removed it seems. While I still see the attribute in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/63c04893a98a713c9d5939ac0b6c4555612d572b/src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.inlineCompletionsAdditions.d.ts#L40, I don't see it in the latest proposed DTS file that was downloaded. It looks like this instead:
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 *  Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

declare module 'vscode' {

    // https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124024 @hediet

    export namespace languages {
        /**
         * Registers an inline completion provider.
         *
         * Multiple providers can be registered for a language. In that case providers are asked in
         * parallel and the results are merged. A failing provider (rejected promise or exception) will
         * not cause a failure of the whole operation.
         *
         * @param selector A selector that defines the documents this provider is applicable to.
         * @param provider An inline completion provider.
         * @param metadata Metadata about the provider.
         * @return A {@link Disposable} that unregisters this provider when being disposed.
         */
        export function registerInlineCompletionItemProvider(selector: DocumentSelector, provider: InlineCompletionItemProvider, metadata: InlineCompletionItemProviderMetadata): Disposable;
    }

    export interface InlineCompletionItem {
        /**
         * If set to `true`, unopened closing brackets are removed and unclosed opening brackets are closed.
         * Defaults to `false`.
        */
        completeBracketPairs?: boolean;
    }

    export interface InlineCompletionItemProviderMetadata {
        /**
         * Specifies a list of extension ids that this provider yields to if they return a result.
         * If some inline completion provider registered by such an extension returns a result, this provider is not asked.
         */
        yieldTo: string[];
    }

    export interface InlineCompletionItemProvider {
        /**
         * @param completionItem The completion item that was shown.
         * @param updatedInsertText The actual insert text (after brackets were fixed).
         */
        // eslint-disable-next-line local/vscode-dts-provider-naming
        handleDidShowCompletionItem?(completionItem: InlineCompletionItem, updatedInsertText: string): void;

        /**
         * Is called when an inline completion item was accepted partially.
         * @param acceptedLength The length of the substring of the inline completion that was accepted already.
         */
        // eslint-disable-next-line local/vscode-dts-provider-naming
        handleDidPartiallyAcceptCompletionItem?(completionItem: InlineCompletionItem, acceptedLength: number): void;

        /**
         * Is called when an inline completion item was accepted partially.
         * @param info Additional info for the partial accepted trigger.
         */
        // eslint-disable-next-line local/vscode-dts-provider-naming
        handleDidPartiallyAcceptCompletionItem?(completionItem: InlineCompletionItem, info: PartialAcceptInfo): void;
    }

    export interface PartialAcceptInfo {
        kind: PartialAcceptTriggerKind;
    }

    export enum PartialAcceptTriggerKind {
        Unknown = 0,
        Word = 1,
        Line = 2,
        Suggest = 3,
    }

    // When finalizing `commands`, make sure to add a corresponding constructor parameter.
    export interface InlineCompletionList {
        /**
         * A list of commands associated with the inline completions of this list.
         */
        commands?: Command[];

        /**
         * When set and the user types a suggestion without derivating from it, the inline suggestion is not updated.
         * Defaults to false (might change).
         */
        enableForwardStability?: boolean;
    }
}

What is the best way to suppress intellisense when displaying inline completions?

At least at the time of this writing, I think you can't. If you want to know why I think that, trace the following:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/a1f2ea3162c704a5890c35dde4df6ee46283d957/src/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/browser/suggestModel.ts#L113 -> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/a1f2ea3162c704a5890c35dde4df6ee46283d957/src/vs/editor/contrib/inlineCompletions/browser/inlineCompletionContextKeys.ts#L40 -> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/a1f2ea3162c704a5890c35dde4df6ee46283d957/src/vs/workbench/api/common/extHostLanguageFeatures.ts#L1390 (hardcoded to false)
Also, the fact that it was intentionally removed from the experimental API due to feedback. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190727.
I'd be happy to be wrong though.
